# How to make a variable get multiple values from a single cell and use it as autofilter criteria

Tags: excel, vba, autofilter

I have a single cell with multiple values, sometimes can it have just one value or it can contains 10/20 and so on. I whant use this info on that specific cell as criteria to autofilter. All values in this cell are using comma between then.

I have tried alot of array/transpose/range combination but without success

```
Sub Filtro()

Dim FILTROMANUAL As Variant

Set FILTROMANUAL = Sheets("21.03 a 20.04").Range("AL7")

ActiveSheet.Range("$A:$AH").AutoFilter Field:=28, Criteria1:=FILTROMANUAL, Operator:=xlFilterValues

End Sub
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need an array of values. Using `Split` on the cell will give you that:

```
ActiveSheet.Range("$A:$AH").AutoFilter Field:=28, Criteria1:=Split(FILTROMANUAL.Value, ","), Operator:=xlFilterValues
```

Comment: I'm getting a Incompatible Types error using your code.

Comment: Can you share some sample criteria data from `FILTROMANUAL`? Also, `Dim FILTROMANUAL As Range`, not `As Variant`.

Comment: On the cell I have this: 4061491414, 5430490934, 743170733, 5392490936, 5422490939, 1645490146, 25494325
That is what is inside the variant

Comment: Still can't reproduce the error. What is the exact error message?

Comment: This is the code I'm using:

<code>

Sub Filtro()

Dim FILTROMANUAL As Range

Set FILTROMANUAL = Sheets("21.03 a 20.04").Range("AL7")

ActiveSheet.Range("$A:$AH").AutoFilter Field:=28, Criteria1:=Split(FILTROMANUAL.Value, ","), Operator:=xlFilterValues

End Sub

<code>

I'm getting:

Execution error timer "13":

Incompatibles Types

Comment: Just to check, you get `4061491414, 5430490934, 743170733, 5392490936, 5422490939, 1645490146, 25494325` if you `Debug.Print FILTROMANUAL.value`?

Comment: I got it @BigBen! I don't know why but the cell has 4 spaces before the actual data. Withou the spaces it worked flawlessly. Only have to instruct the user for not leaving spaces. Thank you very much!

Comment: Cool, glad to help out! If the spaces might be an issue in the future you could add a `Trim` to remove them.